# Can anything be 'more hydrating than water'?

Tags: nutrition, water

Some sports drinks, and even [vegetables](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-1200531/The-vegetables-hydrate-glass-water.html) claim to be 'more hydrating than water'. What does this even mean? How is 'hydration' even measured? If I ate enough cucumbers could I survive without ever drinking anything at all?

Comment: *Chuckles at "How is 'hydration' even measured?"*

Comment: Related sister site question [How much sea water can I safely drink?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/9920/4079)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

They seem to measure hydration by seeing how much of the fluid stays in the body instead of being secreted.

For milk there a [study](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=1057236) with describes the process:

> Urine samples were collected before
>   and for 5 h after exercise to assess
>   fluid balance. Urine excretion over
>   the recovery period did not change
>   during the milk trials whereas there
>   was a marked increase in output
>   between 1 and 2 h after drinking water
>   and the sports drink. Cumulative urine
>   output was less after the milk drinks
>   were consumed (611 (sd 207) and 550
>   (sd 141) ml for milk and milk with
>   added sodium, respectively, compared
>   to 1184 (sd 321) and 1205 (sd 142) ml
>   for the water and sports drink; P <
>   0·001). Subjects remained in net
>   positive fluid balance or euhydrated
>   throughout the recovery period after
>   drinking the milk drinks but returned
>   to net negative fluid balance 1 h
>   after drinking the other drinks.

Comment: Who is “they”? This is the only *meaningful* measure of hydration.

Comment: By this measurement, swallowing a water balloon is the most hydrating option.

Comment: "I'm not edematous; I'm hydrated!"

Comment: "They" are the authors of the linked study - Shirreffs, Watson and Maughan.

Comment: There are 2 problems with this study: 1) The amount of water in milk is about 10% lower than in the same amount of sports drink, which is one of the reasons that drinking milk results in lower amount of urine. 2) The composition (sodium, sugar) of sports drink is not known (at least not from this abstract).

Comment: @Jan : Having to read more then the abstract is typing for scientific paper if you care for the details. It's no sign that the study has flaws.

Comment: Do you have a link to a free full article? What I mean is this: In [this study](https://academic.oup.com/ajcn/article/103/3/717/4564598), there's a [graph](https://academic.oup.com/view-large/figure/110158701/ajcn114769fig2.gif), which shows that orange juice has a "beverage hydrating index" almost as high as oral rehydration solution (based on the same principle as you've mentioned - lower urine excretion than after plain water). But orange juice has 10% less water, so when they adjusted for equal amounts of water in a beverage, orange juice was not significantly more hydrating than water...

Comment: OK; I have found the full article: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/6370377_Milk_as_an_effective_post-exercise_rehydration_drink/link/552414250cf2b123c51733be/download . You can put it in your answer if you want.

Answer (score 14):

**Question: Can anything be more hydrating than plain water?**

**Short answer:**

- Yes, fluids that contain certain amount of sugars and sodium can be more hydrating than plain water, which can be beneficial in prevention or treatment of dehydration during prolonged endurance exercise ([Nutrition & Metabolism, 2009](https://nutritionandmetabolism.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1743-7075-6-9)).
- In everyday life, when you are not dehydrated and when you are not very physically active, there is probably no practical benefit from regular drinking "more hydrating" beverages, which may be even harmful, because of potentially excessive sugar and sodium intake.

**Question: How can be a hydration potential of a beverage measured?**

**Short answer:**

- By measuring *the speed of absorption* of water from a certain beverage. For example, water from **sports drinks** with 4-8% of sugar can be absorbed faster than water from plain water, so they are intended for hydration *during* exercise ([Journal of Athletic Training, 2000](https://www.nata.org/sites/default/files/FluidReplacementsForAthletes.pdf)).
- By measuring *fluid retention,* that is the time during which the water from a beverage stays in your body before being excreted ([IJSNEM, 2017](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28253022)). **Sports drinks** with sufficient amount of sodium and **oral rehydration solution (ORS)** can improve water retention.

---

**1) What is good (appropriate) hydration of the body and how it can be evaluated?**

*"At home"* you can say that you are well hydrated when you don't have symptoms of dehydration, which include dry mouth, thirst, strong yellow urine, [prolonged skin turgor](https://medlineplus.gov/ency/imagepages/17223.htm) and sudden loss of body weight (1 L water = 1 kg weight) within hours/few days ([MedlinePlus](https://medlineplus.gov/dehydration.html)).

*A doctor* can further evaluate your hydration status by a *combination* of tests, such as the levels of sodium in your blood and urine (but this is beyond the scope of this answer).

**2) Can anything be more hydrating than plain water and how can you measure that?**

Beverages that contain sugars and sodium can be more hydrating than plain water. *Sugars increase the rate of water absorption* (but probably not more than ~10%: [Fig 1: blue (G0) = plain water, yellow (G3) = a solution with 3% glucose](https://nutritionandmetabolism.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1743-7075-6-9#Fig1)) and *sodium prolong the time by which the water stays in your body before being excreted.* Both effects have been measured in studies:

> The absorption of *glucose* in the jejunum will lead to increased fluid
>   absorption. *Sodium* is also important for rehydration after a period of dehydration as sodium helps with fluid retention. *([Nutrition and Metabolism, 2009](https://nutritionandmetabolism.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1743-7075-6-9))*
>
> The purpose of this study was to examine the efficacy of water and a
>   50 mmol/L NaCl solution on postexercise rehydration when a standard
>   meal was consumed during rehydration. Eight healthy participants took
>   part in two experimental trials during which they lost 1.5 ± 0.4% of
>   initial body mass via intermittent exercise in the heat. Participants
>   then rehydrated over a 60-min period with water or a 50 mmol/L NaCl
>   solution in a volume equivalent to 150% of their body mass loss during
>   exercise. In addition, a standard meal was ingested during this time
>   which was equivalent to 30% of participants predicted daily energy
>   expenditure. Urine samples were collected before and after exercise
>   and for 3 hr after rehydration. Cumulative urine volume (981 ± 458 ml
>   and 577 ± 345 mL; p = .035) was greater, while **percentage fluid
>   retained (50 and 70%) was lower during the water compared with the
>   NaCl trial respectively.** *([International Journal of Sport Nutrition
>   and Exercise Metabolism, 2017](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28253022))*

**3) What exactly can be more hydrating than plain water?**

**a) Sports drinks**

> If **CHOs** are included in the fluid, the concentration should be **4% to
>   8%.** Concentrations higher than 8% slow the rate of fluid absorption.
>
> Small quantities of **sodium** may enhance palatability and
>   retention...Sodium concentration should be approximately **0.3 to 0.7
>   g/L.**
>
> *CHOs = carbohydrates = sugar; 0.3 to 0.7 g sodium/L = 13.2-30 mmol sodium/L; ([National Athletic Trainers’ Association Position Statement: Fluid Replacement for Athletes, Journal of Athletic Training, 2000](https://www.nata.org/sites/default/files/FluidReplacementsForAthletes.pdf))*

**b) [Oral rehydration solution (ORS)](https://apps.who.int/medicinedocs/en/d/Js4950e/2.4.html),** released by World Health Organization is similar to sports drinks, but contains more sodium (75 mmol/L) than most sports drinks. ORS is mainly intended to treat dehydration in children "at home," for example, due to diarrhea. It's main purpose is to prevent hyponatremia, which could develop after drinking high amounts of plain water, which contains almost no sodium.

**4. How hydrating can be vegetables and fruits?**

Vegetables and fruits, which can contain more than 90% of water, are hydrating, but because they are solid, they pass through the stomach into the small intestine slower than liquids ([Colostate.edu](http://www.vivo.colostate.edu/hbooks/pathphys/digestion/stomach/emptying.html)), so they are absorbed slower and do not hydrate you as quickly as liquids. But yes, you can get enough water by eating only cucumbers (probably from at least 1.5-2 kg of them per day...).

**5. How can sodium be beneficial for hydration if it is known to cause body swelling (edema) and dehydration?**

Sodium in beverages, where it is present in relatively low amounts (<1 g/liter) can be **beneficial during a prolonged exercise,** like a marathon, because:

- it replaces the sodium lost by sweating and prolongs the time during which water stays in your body and thus decreases the frequency of drinking and urination.
- prevents [dilutional hyponatremia](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4470181/?report=classic) after drinking large amount of fluid.

Sodium, acutely or regularly consumed in large amounts (>5 g/day) is usually *excessive* sodium, which can be **harmful,** because:

- it may [increase blood pressure in some people](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4520886/?report=classic).
- it can cause dehydration, when consumed in grossly excessive amounts, for example when [drinking seawater](https://books.google.com/books?id=krLSCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA373&lpg=PA373&dq=kidney%20urine%20concentration%20ability%20seawater&source=bl&ots=ZBnVktECYW&sig=yJ7xaF3POeo_UjRyTnoATKszmy8&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=kidney%20urine%20concentration%20ability%20seawater&f=false), because excessive sodium, when excreted through the kidneys drags some water with it.

Comment: The statement "Yes, certain fluids that contain sodium and/or sugar, can be more hydrating than plain water; sugar promotes water absorption and sodium promotes fluid retention." is not supported by the references.  The most the references support is that "sodium **may** enhance palatability and retention," it is equally likely that it **MAY NOT**.  Most of this answer is about replacing electrolytes and carbs, "Hydration is the process of replacing water in the body."

Comment: @JamesJenkins, my answer is purely about hydration. Sugars do promote water absorption and sodium does promote water retention, as shown in several studies; I included a study in which they measured their effects. Sodium has an additional role in preventing dilutional hyponatremia, which is why fluids with sodium are _necessary_ when replacing large amounts of fluids in severe dehydration.

Comment: @Jan There is a difference between getting hydrated and getting bloated. Stuff with sugar and sodium keep more water _inside_ your body, but it doesn't mean this water is accessible for your body to use. Case in point - seawater is full of sodium, and nevertheless will kill you dehydrated.

Comment: @T.Sar-ReinstateMonica, I don't get it. Did you think water retention = bloating? In the context of better hydration, water retention means _longer_ water retention, not swelling.

Comment: @Jan No, I'm saying that a lot of people mix up water that you keep inside your body and water that your body can actually use. The reason sodium raises water retention isn't because it "helps your body get hydrated". Instead, it does the opposite - it raises how much water your body needs to be hydrated and forces you to maintain a larger stockpile of it. Being hydrated and retaining water isn't the same thing.

Comment: Jan I don't understand what you mean by "longer water retention" Water only does your body good (for the most part) if it in in your blood or the cells of your body.  If you over hydrate your kidneys will expel extra If you also the point by @T.Sar-ReinstateMonica about increasing sodium.

Comment: @T.Sar-ReinstateMonica I think the point you are trying to make is explained in [this answer](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/9924/4079)

Comment: @T.Sar-ReinstateMonica, copy-paste from my first quote: "Percentage fluid retained (50 and 70%) was lower during the water compared with the NaCl trial respectively." The full quote is in my [other answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/45681/15288). It means that if you drink a beverage with sodium in it, the water will stay longer in your blood, because sodium will help keep it in. The other way around: After, let's say 2 hours, you will have more water in your blood if you drink a beverage with sodium than after drinking plain water.

Comment: @Jan Water retention and being hydrated aren't the same. You can have a lot of water stashed in your body, but because your sodium levels are too high, your body can't use it for anything. This thing "more sodium=more hydration" is the thing that almost got several people dead with that dammed Jilly Juice scam.

Comment: @T.Sar-ReinstateMonica, we are not talking about _additional_ sodium here, but about the replacement of sodium lost by sweat. This has nothing to do with sodium loading. Do you agree that this works with intravenous saline infusion? It's to maintain the sodium concentration in your body fluids. Also, if some fluid goes from the blood to extracellular fluid, it's not already lost, because it can go back to the blood.

Comment: If you infuse plain water intravenously, it will be quickly excreted in order to correct hyponatremia. Do you agree? It's the same principle with drinking beverages with sodium.

Comment: @Jan That's not the point of the question, nor from your answer, however. You answer doesn't say "replacing lost sodium", it just says "more sodium = better hydratation". If you qualify it further, I'll gladly agree with you, but as it stands now it is grossly misinformative. Drinking sports drinks or sodium-loaded beverages when your body _doesn't need_ extra sodium has risks that should be accounted for.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. I changed my downvote into an upvote. Your answer looks quite better now.